# A null value should be considered as 0 when addition of it is done with decimal value

Tags: c#, winforms, null, datacolumn

There are three column in the datatable `A,B and C`. Now each column is type of `decimal`. Now I am doing like `dt.Columns["A"].Expression="B+C";` to make addition of Column B's record and column C's record. Now if there is any value of `B or C` is `null` then addition of B and C will be null like B's value is 3 and C's value is `null` for first row then `B+C(3+null)` will be `null` which is not appropriate, the result of addition should be `3`.If I replace `0` instead of `null` then it will be ok.But whereever there is null value in the records it should be remain it is and it should not be replaced by `0`.That is null value **should not** be replaced by `0` and when addition of null value is done with any decimal value `null` value should be considered as `0`.

Is it possible,how can we do this ?

**EDIT**
See the following answer 
where
`dt.Rows[0]["B"] = DBNull.Value;`
but I have problem like according to my code I can not assign `DBNull.Value` directly `dt.Rows[0]["B"] = DBNull.Value;` I have to store it in one variable of type `object` like 
`Object obj;`
`obj=DBNull.Value` 
and then that value goes to the table.Then it gives error like `null value can not be stored to the column B.`

Comment: Your boss asks you what the sales are for January. 1.6 million, you answer. February? 2.1 million. March? I don't know. What's the total for the quarter? Is the answer 3.7 million, or "I don't know"?  Answering 3.7 million when you don't know what the sales for March were is *lying*. Are you sure that you want to substitute zero for null? That's saying that any quantity you don't know the value of is zero; the real quantity might be nowhere near zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
dt.Columns["A"].Expression = "ISNULL(B, 0) + ISNULL(C, 0)";
```

Full working test:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(decimal));

dt.Rows.Add();
dt.Rows[0]["B"] = DBNull.Value;
dt.Rows[0]["C"] = 3;

dt.Columns["A"].Expression = "ISNULL(B, 0) + ISNULL(C, 0)";
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0]["A"]);
```

Comment: @Anthony Pegram,Sir,What does mean for `?` and what does `a ?? 0 + b ?? 0` do ?

Comment: @Anthony,Sir it gives error `DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.`

Comment: I've updated the answer. The original post was not suited for what you were trying to do, I apologize.

Comment: @Anthony,Sir,does `ISNULL` replace 0 instead of `null` value or what it does ?

Comment: `ISNULL(x, y)` is a native SQL Server function supported, in this case, as a datatable expression that will return x unless it is null, in which case it will return y. The result in my example is `0 + 3`.

Comment: @Mr Anthony,Can we assign DBNull.Value to string variable ?

Comment: You can certainly use DBNull.Value in a string field in a table, provided the field allows nulls.